# in plot how to create space left to y axis so as to display axis name comfortably

Tags: r, plot

In a plot, how to create space left to y-axis so as to display axis name comfortably? The y-axis name gets cuts off on the left side.

```
tiff(file = "plot_y2.tiff", width = 6200, height = 6200, units = "px", res = 300)

xax <- c(0, 1, -1) #x axis of the plot

plot(xax, pp.sd_bmi1[c(1, 3, 5), 3], type="n",
 xlim=c(-1 , 1),  
 ylim=c(0.0001, 0.0014),
 xlab="name of x axis",

 ylab="Probability of having a infection with complications",
 cex.lab=3, #axis label size
 cex.axis=3,
 family="serif" #make the font times new roman
)
## saving defaults in `op`
op <- par(family = "serif")

axis(side = 1, at=seq(0,2,0.5), labels=FALSE, tcl= -0.5, lwd=3)
axis(side = 2, labels=FALSE, lwd=3)
box(lwd=3) #border width

lines(xax,pp.sd_bmi1[c(1, 3, 5), 3],type="o",pch=0,lty=1,col="red",cex=3,lwd=3)

lines(xax,pp.sd_bmi1[c(2, 4, 6), 3],type="o",pch=4,lty=2,col="blue",cex=3,lwd=3) 

#Add a legend to the plot and set legend 
legend("topright", legend = c("No wt. education", "wt education"),
   col = c("red", "blue"), lty = 1:2, cex = 3)
## reset plotting parameters
par(op)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Before your first plot,  use `par` to set the margins.  If you type `par("mar")` you will see the default is 5.1 4.1 4.1 2.1. The second value (4.1) controls the size of the left margin. Just increase that with something like `par(mar=c(5.1,7,4.1,2.1))`

Comment: that works, I was placing that on the wrong line before; otherwise, it's a duplicate of some already posted solution; Thanx for highlighting location@G5W